# Is there a way to rebuild Code::Blocks code completion database?

Tags: codeblocks

I would like some data structures to be studied by Code::Blocks and made available via its code completion feature.

Something similar could be done in SlickEdit.

How to do that in Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer here http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Q:_How_do_I_get_Code_Completion_to_work.3F

In short, project properties dialog contains "C/C++ parser options" where a path can be added. After the project is reopened - the path is be parsed and code completions becomes aware of the new symbols. Magic.

Comment: thanks, I just didn't perform enough googling though... but now since it's on SO - it might be helpful for others like me :)